# Error while loading tsv file in spark on google colab

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
<b>file_loc = 'T3.tsv'
T3_df = spark.read.csv(file_loc, header=False, sep="\t")</b>
```

I am getting input/output error saying Py4JJavaError while reading a file--

An error occurred while calling o29.csv. :

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Input/output error at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:163) at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)